# как остановить анимацию блока в определенной точке используя JQ

Tags: javascript, html, css, запрос

Я пытаюсь заставить div «box» перестать двигаться по экрану и остаться сразу после конца дива «banner»

как тут:
[image: пример]

как это возможно?

```js
$(function(){
  $('.banner').hide().slideDown(800);
  $('.banner h1').hide().show().addClass('animateText')
  $('.box').hide()
  var $win = $(window);

  $win.on("scroll", function () {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();
    $('.banner h1').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + top + 'deg)'})

    if (top > 150){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':0})
      $('.banner p').slideDown(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': top*1.2 + 'px'})
      $('.box').slideDown(600)
      $('.box').css({'transform': 'translateY(' + top/2 + 'px)'})
      
    } else if(top < 400){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':1})
      $('.banner p').slideUp(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': '-400px', 'transition':'600ms'})
      $('.box').slideUp(1000);
      
    } 
    
    //типа как тут:
    if(top>$('.banner').outerHeight()){
      $('.box').stopRightWhereYouAre()
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.banner{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.animateText{
  animation: slide 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    margin-left: -800px
  }
  50%{
    font-size: 350px;
  }
  100%{
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner p{
  color:white;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -17%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color:black;
  top:250px;
  left:-400px;
  position: absolute;

}

.box{
  background-color: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.h{
  margin-bottom: 300vh
}

.box p{
  color:white;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <div class="rotate"><h2>DESIGN</h2></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @humster_spb сделала

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то Вам надо:
1. Убрать отрицательные маргин-топы у блоков
2. Убрать трансформацию box при скролле

```js
$(function(){
  $('.banner').hide().slideDown(800);
  $('.banner h1').hide().show().addClass('animateText')
  $('.box').hide()
  var $win = $(window);

  $win.on("scroll", function () {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();
    $('.banner h1').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + top + 'deg)'})

    if (top > 150){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':0})
      $('.banner p').slideDown(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': top*1.2 + 'px'})
      $('.box').slideDown(600)
      //$('.box').css({'transform': 'translateY(' + top/2 + 'px)'})
      
    } else if(top < 400){
      $('.banner h1').css({'opacity':1})
      $('.banner p').slideUp(800);
      $('.banner h2').css({'left': '-400px', 'transition':'600ms'})
      $('.box').slideUp(1000);
      
    } 
    
    //типа как тут:
    /*if(top>$('.banner').outerHeight()){
      $('.box').stopRightWhereYouAre()
    }*/ 
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.banner{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300px;
  padding-top: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.animateText{
  animation: slide 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    margin-left: -800px
  }
  50%{
    font-size: 350px;
  }
  100%{
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.banner p{
  color:white;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  /*margin-top: -17%;*/
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color:black;
  top:250px;
  left:-400px;
  position: absolute;

}

.box{
  background-color: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 40%;
  /*margin-top: -400px;*/
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.h{
  margin-bottom: 300vh
}

.box p{
  color:white;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  <div class="rotate"><h2>DESIGN</h2></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо! но тогда блок не будет двигаться совсем.. а мне нужно как в самом начале загрузки. ну.. чтобы он появился, спустился вниз по скроллу и остановился после конца дива баннер, а он сейчас у меня спускается вниз и не останавливается